# I was testing out my test code for my main code, and it's not throwing any errors even though my main code is wrong

Tags: python, testing

my main code is as follows:

```
def main():
    x = int(input("enter x: "))
    print("x squared is", square(x))


def square(n):
    return n + n
# made + instead of * to check test code


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and my test code is as follows:

```
from app import square

def main():
    test_square


def test_square():
    if square(2) != 4:
        print("2 squares was not 4")
    if square(3) != 9:
        print("3 squared was not 9")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

in my main code I deliberately changed * to + to check whether my test code is working or not, and it didn't throw any errors at me so its not

ChatGPT is telling me I potentially have something wrong with my IDE but my IDE has been running as expected since 2 weeks when I installed it and I hadn't faced problems before this.

Comment: You never call `test_square`.

Comment: btw, 2+2 = 2*2 = 4, so only the "3" test will fail when you change `*` to `+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a typo in the test code.

It should be

```
def main():
    test_square()
```

instead of

```
def main():
    test_square
```

Comment: Typos are reasons to close the question, not post an answer.